# How to scale Android ImageView width according to layout_alignTop and layout_alignBottom

Tags: android, imageview, scale, measure

I'd like to have a simple player view with image, name and status. The image will be loaded via Google+.

The Problem I have is that with big images my ImageView get's far too wide and pushes my texts out of sight.

Here is an example to show how it looks like:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11037539/unwanted_padding.png

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/playerPane"
    android:background="@color/player2">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/playerName"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/playerStatus"
        android:id="@+id/playerImage"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_picture"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playerImage"
        android:id="@+id/playerName"
        android:text="Player"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/player_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/player_padding"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/playerName"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/playerName"
        android:id="@+id/playerStatus"
        android:text="status"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/player_padding" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried all ImageView.scaleTypes, but so far nothing works..

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: that happens with imageviews. I usually set the width to a fixed dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define your width. It should fix it. So change this line

to something like:

```
   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="75dp" //OR WHATEVER LOOKS BEST
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did so and removed "layout_alignTop and Bottom", and it works well :).

Comment: @DanBad. Oh yeah, I didn't notice that. That is not good practice to have that. But glad to help

Answer (score 0):

ScaleType is only really useful when the imageview's size is smaller than the image.  As previously mentioned, set the size and then you can use the scaleType to fix how the image should be scaled within the now smaller area.